# Prove that if $\sum_nU_n$ is convergent. Then $\sum_n U_n^2$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that $\sum_n U_n$ is cgt therefore $\underset{n}{\lim} U_n = 0$
and by definition of limit
$0- \varepsilon < U_n < 0+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$
but I don't know how to get to $\sum_nU_n^2.$

P. S.  Here $\sum_nU_n$ is series of positive terms.

Comment: Eventually $U_n^2< U_n$.

Comment: The essential information about positivity of $U_n$'s shouldn't be part of a PS-statement.

Comment: i know... sorry i was in a hurry !!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that:                  $$\sum U_n^2<\left(\sum U_n\right)^2$$       :)

Comment: @nicomezi the summands are positive so we can assure a more strong inequality

Comment: I said that the summands are positive and 0 is not positive

Comment: I see, I am not very familair with the way English language deals with those considerations. In French, a positive number can be $0$ (and we say "strictly positive" to mean that it can be $0$ ).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not comfortable with Cauchy-Schwarz: You correctly say that $U_n\to 0$ and so there is an $N$ such that $|U_n|< 1$ for all $n\geq N$. Thus $|U_n|^2\leq |U_n|$ for all $n\geq N$. Thus
$$
\sum_n U_n^2 \leq \sum_{n< N} U_n^2 + \sum_{n\geq N} |U_n| < \infty.
$$